# TestDisk won't detect partition, but PhotoRec does

Tags: testdisk

I have a small problem, I accidentally formatted one of my drives in Windows.

PhotoRec finds the partition, but Testdisk doesn’t.
[image: PhotoRec]

[image: TestDisk]

Help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: It finds the partition when partition table type is "None"

Comment: Did you press Enter on Testdisk when it got that far then select Deeper Search to see if it can find your old partition?

Comment: See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for help.

Comment: I did try a deeper search. Didn't find anything. I've read through that link as well.

Comment: `EDIT: It finds the partition when partition table type is "None"` THANK YOU SO MUCH this was my problem, i was picking Intel/PC because that's what it was

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was able to fix it.

I went to superblock while in non-partitioned mode. and then it just told me to use a command, here’s it:

fsck.ext4 -p -b 163840 -B 4096 /dev/sde

in case anybody from the future reads this. 153840 being one of the superblock numbers, 4096 being the size and /dev/sde being the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually tools like these you mentioned are using base commands and files . First command I suggest to use is `fdisk` . It's powerful oldschool command .

```
$ fdisk /dev/sda
```

This will give shell . Try `p` to show your partition  . Also you can use files in proc directory

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
```

This will show all partition that Kernel will care of and command `partprobe` can regenerate this file . 
some cases you can not find your partition anymore. try using following procedure :

1. make partition with `fdisk` .
2. make file system with `mkfs` .
3. mount your partition with `mount` .

Comment: I get this warning/error "The size of this disk is 3.7 TiB (4000787030016 bytes). DOS partition table format can not be used on drives for volumes larger than 2199023255040 bytes for 512-byte sectors. Use GUID partition table format (GPT).
"

Comment: @KimAndré That right. It's exactly as it says. For volumes of 2TB+ the old "msdos" (MBR) partition table cannot be used.

Comment: well it seems you using GPT then your `fdisk` command turns to `gdisk` .

Comment: And howp exactly does this help? My partition is deleted.

Comment: You want to recover your partition ? As your pictures said you have ext3 partition which not shown in your linux ?! so If superblock lost on that partition it's not recoverable .